# certbot renew when not using default directory

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

Created certificates using --work-dir flag. So all of my certs are stored in a directory that is not the default letsencrypt directory. When I run certbot renew, I get the following:

No renewals were attempted.

I can't find documentation anywhere that explains how I would indicate where the certs are that need renew. Anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Looks to me like certbot accepts a --work-dir argument.

Comment: Yeah that's what I use on creation but to me it doesn't appear to work when I use it during the certbot renew command.

Comment: It's not as simple as there being no certs that need to be renewed?

Comment: No, I wish it was. I do believe I figured it out. I'm about to respond with the answer in case someone else runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved my own issue. So, for anyone that runs into this here is my scenario.

On initial creation I used certonly and --config-dir, work-dir, logs-dir and the -w flag.

Once I included all of those flags to the renew command and the appropriate directories the command worked as expected.

I'm not sure if all of those flags are necessary but including them made it work for me.